# How to solve L1 optimization of Low-Rank matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, matrix-decomposition, regularization, nuclear-norm

I am trying to solve the following problem but have some difficulties. Any ideas? Any leads?

$$ \min_{A,C} \|C\|_* +\alpha\|X-A\|_1  \text{ s.t. }   A=AC $$
$\|*\|_1$ is the sum of absolute values of the matrix elements

The model is :

- $X$ - is the given data
- $A$ - is clean representative of the data.
- $C$- is the the sparse matrix of the data
- $||C||_*$ is the nuclear norm of matrix C
- $\alpha$ - is some regulator.

Comment: What is $\| \cdot \|_*$? Also, if you're optimizing over $C$, how do you know that it is sparse?

Comment: $||C||_*$ is the nuclear norm of the matrix C. Optimizing over it will cause the matrix C to be sparse. For definition of the nuclear norm you case see section 3 at :
http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~akshaykr/files/matrix_norms.pdf

Comment: Quick Latex point: for matrix and vector norms `$\| v \|$` is typically preferred over `$|| v ||$`

Comment: What are the dimensions? Is $A$ fat? Thin? Square? Full rank?

Comment: $A$ is a full rank matrix (specifically I assume $X=A+E$ and $A=AC$. $A$ is the clean data while $X$ is the measured data